# How can I use mac to print, as an intermediate computer?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing

Here is the situation: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, we have a printer(Lenovo-LJ2650DN) in our office's local network. Everyone is printing via the local network, but I can't!

Why?

Because there is no corresponding driver of that printer for linux. However, my colleague is using a mac computer, he can print using his computer. We are in the same local network. I've turned his "sharing printer" on, and I can find his shared printer through my computer. However I still can't print, I thought I could print via his computer as an intermediate.

**Do I still need to install the driver, how can I print?**

I really can't find the printer drive for ubuntu.

Comment: printer model would be great :)

Comment: @MiHa Lenove-LJ2650DN